# update a listbox item

Tags: c#

i want from my program to select a listbox item and then update it.i have a list ecoItems.Eco is a class with 2 store variables,one string and one double variable.SetEcoValues is a set Method take two values,one string and one double.i try this code but don't change anything.any suggestions?

```
         private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            Eco y;
            y = ecoItems.ElementAt<Eco>(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            y.SetEcoValues(textBox1.Text,Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
            listBox5.Items.Insert(listBox1.SelectedIndex, y);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code and what I would guess is your class, I'd do something like this:

```
class Eco {
  public Eco() { }
  public void SetEcoValues(string text, double value) {
    Text = text;
    Value = value;
  }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
  public override string ToString() {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)) {
      return Text;
    }
    return base.ToString();
  }
}

ListView listView1; // initialized somewhere, I presume.

void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if ((listView1.SelectedItems != null) || (0 < listView1.SelectedItems.Count)) {
    ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    Eco y = item.Tag as Eco;
    if (y == null) {
      y = new Eco();
    }
    y.SetEcoValues(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
    item.Text = y.Text;
    if (item.SubItems.Count < 2) {
      item.SubItems.Add(y.Value.ToString());
    } else {
      item.SubItems[1].Text = y.Value.ToString();
    }
    item.Tag = y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually getting the ListItem anywhere, and trying to add something to the ListBox which isn't a ListItem. You could try something like so:

```
ListItem Item = listBox1.SelectedItem;

//Update the Text and Values
Item.Text = textBox1.Text,;
Item.Value = textBox2.Text;
```

Or... if you have the ListBox Bound to your list of Ecos and want it updated, instead of listBox5.Items.Insert... you would need to re bind it.

```
listBox5.DataSource = y;
listBox5.DataBind();
```

Comment: I kind of wonder if he has his list bound to his listbox and wants a change reflected in the listbox. Maybe that's why he never changes a listbox item and tries to insert an Eco object into the listbox.

Comment: @Yatrix You may be right, hard to tell from his code sample. I guess in that case he needs to update his list of Eco and then re-bind the entire list

Comment: yes Yatrix that i want to do.an immediate change to the listbox.can i do that?

Comment: @lekoarmin i updated the sample with the option of rebinding the list, which it sounds like what you need to do.

Comment: @lekoarmin: I was composing my answer while everyone was commenting on the data binding. My answer does not show data binding, but data binding can be accommodated.

Comment: @lekoarmin Yes. As Doozer mentioned, you'll have to rebind your list to the listbox. You may want to look into other collections if it'd not be too much work. Some of them will update a control automatically when the collection is changed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx is one for example. Depending on how much data is in your list, rebinding may not be the best solution and you'll have to do things manually.