# How to make multiple listboxes change the value when one of the value in a listbox is clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, listbox

Please forgive my grammar.
currently i have some codes that works perfectly on VB which make make multiple listbox move when one of the value in a listbox is selected, my question is can some one help me to convert these code to c#? thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub ListBox5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox5.Click, ListBox4.Click, ListBox3.Click, ListBox2.Click, ListBox1.Click
        Dim lb As New ListBox
        lb = sender
        If lb.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex
            ListBox2.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex
            ListBox3.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex
            ListBox4.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex
            ListBox5.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex
            txtsn.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
            txtsa.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem
            txtsadd.Text = ListBox3.SelectedItem
            txtsp.Text = ListBox4.SelectedItem
            txtse.Text = ListBox5.SelectedItem
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743706/update-a-listbox-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need cast.

```
private void ListBox5_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
    if (lb.SelectedIndex != -1) {
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox2.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox3.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox4.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        txtsn.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem;
        txtsa.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem;
        txtsadd.Text = ListBox3.SelectedItem;
        txtsp.Text = ListBox4.SelectedItem;
        txtse.Text = ListBox5.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the answer! as the problem mentioned need a cast which i do not know how to cast, now i knew it, Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Converted

```
   private void ListBox5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    lb = (ListBox)sender;
    if ((lb.SelectedIndex != -1)) {
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox2.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox3.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox4.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex = lb.SelectedIndex;
        txtsn.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem;
        txtsa.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem;
        txtsadd.Text = ListBox3.SelectedItem;
        txtsp.Text = ListBox4.SelectedItem;
        txtse.Text = ListBox5.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=841a569f-485c-444d-9b8d-e5668f85965c

Comment: i get this error when putting these code

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Updated, Please take a look that

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add the following to your constructor, if you didn't tie the `ListBox5_Click` method to the list boxes at design time.

```
ListBox1.Click += ListBox5_Click;
ListBox2.Click += ListBox5_Click;
ListBox3.Click += ListBox5_Click;
ListBox4.Click += ListBox5_Click;
ListBox5.Click += ListBox5_Click;
```

Comment: this works too, but by adding (Listbox)sender to the Listbox lb is much simpler, Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The above lines just tie the click event to all of your listboxes, that way all 5 of them will update the others. The other answers are the ones that actually do the updating.